# Preview a saved PNG in an R device window

Tags: r

Is there a way print an existing PNG file to the device window, for example, let's say that you have saved a plot as PNG but you would like to preview it (for sanity) before placing it in a presentation or a document.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to 'push' the image into the RStudio 'plots' window.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can import it and display it in R,

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

Comment: In what sense? Ie privide code that would push this to rstudio.

Answer (score 18):

Baptiste's answer didn't work for me while using RStudio in Linux.  I had to remove the `system.file()` call.

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG('/path/image.png')
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

Comment: grid::grid.raster(img) does nothing for me in RStudio :(

Comment: There is still something missing in this answer.  `grid::grid.raster(img)` does display the image in a standard R console, but not in a plot window. There is no way to move it on the screen or even close it.  Hence, it is not surprising that it has no effect under RStudio.

Answer (score 5):

Use [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) library for all your image processing needs. It is brought to you as  [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) package to R. See the introductory [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html).

```
install.packages('magick')

img <- magick::image_read('/path/image.png')
plot(img) # or print(img)
```