# R equivalent of Python's open("my.png").read()

Tags: python, r, png

In Python it is easy to read a png file:

```
f = open("my.png", "rb")
f.read()
```

I thought the equivalent in R would be:

```
paste0(readLines("my.png"), collapse = "\n")
```

But this yields a different result than the python code does for the same png file. How would I recreate `open("my.png","rb").read()` in R?

I am not interested in getting an array of RGB or greyscale like the `png` package offers.

Comment: python does it so easily its amazing

Comment: @Carl, one solution is to use `rJython` package to run python inside R

Comment: Is `r <- png::writePNG(img)` what you want? On the R logo sample png it yields `[1] 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49...`

Answer (score 2):

From [Preview a saved PNG in an R device window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319298/preview-a-saved-png-in-an-r-device-window)

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

from https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Image-files

Package pixmap has a function read.pnm to read ‘portable anymap’ images in PBM (black/white), PGM (grey) and PPM (RGB colour) formats. These are also known as ‘netpbm’ formats.

Packages bmp, jpeg and png read the formats after which they are named. See also packages biOps and Momocs, and Bioconductor package EBImage.

TIFF is more a meta-format, a wrapper within which a very large variety of image formats can be embedded. Packages rtiff and tiff can read some of the sub-formats (depending on the external libtiff software against which they are compiled). There some facilities for specialized sub-formats, for example in Bioconductor package beadarray.

Raster files are common in the geographical sciences, and package rgdal provides an interface to GDAL which provides some facilities of its own to read raster files and links to many others.

But

also see

imager package

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html

also see

https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/EBImage/man/EBImage.pdf

another package is

https://github.com/leeroybrun/Bin2PNG

I am sorry but I am limited into a package search to help you

Comment: i think @Carl needs binary output of image file in format `\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00`