# View venn.diagram in RStudio viewer (not just write to file) using VennDiagram?

Tags: r

Using the `VennDiagram` package, we can make a venn diagram like so with the `venn.diagram()` function [like so](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm.html):

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tm)
library(proustr)

# Load dataset from github
data <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/14_SeveralIndepLists.csv", header=TRUE) 
to_remove <- c("_|[0-9]|\\.|function|^id|script|var|div|null|typeof|opts|if|^r$|undefined|false|loaded|true|settimeout|eval|else|artist")
data <- data %>% filter(!grepl(to_remove, word)) %>% filter(!word %in% stopwords('fr')) %>% filter(!word %in% proust_stopwords()$word)

# library
library(VennDiagram)

#Make the plot
venn.diagram(
  x = list(
    data %>% filter(artist=="booba") %>% select(word) %>% unlist() , 
    data %>% filter(artist=="nekfeu") %>% select(word) %>% unlist() , 
    data %>% filter(artist=="georges-brassens") %>% select(word) %>% unlist()
  ),
  category.names = c("Booba (1995)" , "Nekfeu (663)" , "Brassens (471)"),
  filename = 'venn.png',
  output = TRUE ,
  imagetype="png" ,
  height = 480 , 
  width = 480 , 
  resolution = 300,
  compression = "lzw",
  lwd = 1,
  col=c("#440154ff", '#21908dff', '#fde725ff'),
  fill = c(alpha("#440154ff",0.3), alpha('#21908dff',0.3), alpha('#fde725ff',0.3)),
  cex = 0.5,
  fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.cex = 0.3,
  cat.default.pos = "outer",
  cat.pos = c(-27, 27, 135),
  cat.dist = c(0.055, 0.055, 0.085),
  cat.fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.col = c("#440154ff", '#21908dff', '#fde725ff'),
  rotation = 1
)
```

This results in a `.png` written to the working directly.

How can it instead be viewed in the RStudio viewer pane, and also used in RMarkdown docs etc (i.e. just in the same way a regular ggplot or base plots would be viewed)?

Also note, the same question applies to any of the examples found in the `?
venn.diagram` documentation (they all seem to write to file instead of display in the RStudio viewer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should also do the job. I deleted the arguments for readability:

```
...
plt <- venn.diagram(
  filename = NULL,
  cex = 1,
  cat.cex = 1,
  lwd = 2,
  )
grid::grid.draw(plt)
```

From `?venn.diagram`

> filename
>   Filename for image output, or if NULL returns the grid object itself

It seems, you can control almost anything. Again the docs:

> ...    A series of graphical parameters tweaking the plot. See below for
>   details Details
>
> Argument  Venn Sizes  Class   Description
>   cex    1,2,3,4,5  numeric  Vector giving the size for each area label (length = 1/3/7/15 based on set-number)

Thus we need to be able to display `grid` objects. `plot()` and `print()` don't do this job (it seems there is not `print.grid()`).

Answer (score 6):

I usually do:

```r
library(VennDiagram)
set.seed(1)
list1 <- list(A=sample(LETTERS, 12), B=sample(LETTERS, 12))
venn1 <- venn.diagram(list1, filename = NULL)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(venn1)
```

[image]

I think it still writes a log file into the working directory, but not the graph.

You can put two diagrams side by side like this:

```r
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(2)
list2 <- list(A=sample(LETTERS, 16), B=sample(LETTERS, 12))
venn2 <- venn.diagram(list2, filename = NULL)
grid.arrange(gTree(children=venn1),
             gTree(children=venn2),
             ncol=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I figured out **a** way - there may be better way(s). This involves writing to `tempfile()` instead of a file in the working directory and then reading it in with a few extra lines of code

Note: the only changes to the original code are the addition of

- 1 extra line at the start `temp_file <- tempfile()`
- the rewriting of `filename = 'venn.png'` into `filename = temp_file`
- 3 extra lines at the bottom

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tm)
library(proustr)

# Load dataset from github
data <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/14_SeveralIndepLists.csv", header=TRUE) 
to_remove <- c("_|[0-9]|\\.|function|^id|script|var|div|null|typeof|opts|if|^r$|undefined|false|loaded|true|settimeout|eval|else|artist")
data <- data %>% filter(!grepl(to_remove, word)) %>% filter(!word %in% stopwords('fr')) %>% filter(!word %in% proust_stopwords()$word)

# library
library(VennDiagram)

temp_file <- tempfile()

#Make the plot
venn.diagram(
  x = list(
    data %>% filter(artist=="booba") %>% select(word) %>% unlist() , 
    data %>% filter(artist=="nekfeu") %>% select(word) %>% unlist() , 
    data %>% filter(artist=="georges-brassens") %>% select(word) %>% unlist()
  ),
  category.names = c("Booba (1995)" , "Nekfeu (663)" , "Brassens (471)"),
  filename = temp_file,
  output = TRUE ,
  imagetype="png" ,
  height = 480 , 
  width = 480 , 
  resolution = 300,
  compression = "lzw",
  lwd = 1,
  col=c("#440154ff", '#21908dff', '#fde725ff'),
  fill = c(alpha("#440154ff",0.3), alpha('#21908dff',0.3), alpha('#fde725ff',0.3)),
  cex = 0.5,
  fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.cex = 0.3,
  cat.default.pos = "outer",
  cat.pos = c(-27, 27, 135),
  cat.dist = c(0.055, 0.055, 0.085),
  cat.fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.col = c("#440154ff", '#21908dff', '#fde725ff'),
  rotation = 1
)


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909108/5783745
library(png)
img <- readPNG(temp_file)
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

Comment: @Christoph I haven't tried anything else, if there's a smarter way please put it in an answer (I found a way that works but probably isn't ideal)