# How to display a PNG file in RStudio viewer pane?

Tags: r, rstudio

If I have a .PNG file, is there a simple way to display it in the RStudio viewer pane?

Using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319351/2554330 I can display it in the plot pane using

```
library(png)
filename <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")  # or your own file
img <- readPNG(filename)
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

A complicated way to get it into the viewer pane is this:

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
writeLines(as.character(htmltools::img(src=knitr::image_uri(filename))), temp)
getOption("viewer")(temp)
```

but is there a simpler way?  E.g. is there an existing function in some package that does this in one call, like

```
showPNG(filename)
```

?  I could write my code in such a function, but I'd prefer to use someone else's code that has been tested and maybe works in a wider range of environments than just RStudio, etc.

Edited to add:  I've been looking closer at the answer I accepted (because I wanted to avoid depending on the `magick` package), and discovered something that surprised me:  if `filename` is `"preview.png"`, then `getOption("viewer")(filename)` will do the display in the viewer pane.  `magick::image_read` is flexible and handles many other cases, but for me it was basically just copying and renaming the file!

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler" here? The first two things that come to mind are (1) less code and (2) fewer packages

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I've added an example of a simpler solution at the end.  It's simpler for me, maybe not simpler internally.

Comment: thanks. That `rstudioapi::viewer(filename)` doesn't work (it opens in a new window for me, the same behavior as for `utils::browseURL(filename)`) suggests you may be out of luck. You may try asking on the RStudio community... my reading of `?rstudioapi::viewer` suggests it should work but I may be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the R package magick:

```
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 7.0.10.26
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, lcms, pango, rsvg, webp, x11
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript
#> Using 4 threads
# Assuming png package is installed.
filename <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")
image_read(filename)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!  And for anyone else interested:  that prints some information about the image to the console.  To suppress that, use `print(image_read(filename), info = FALSE)`.

Comment: I just triedwith R version 4.0.3, and still works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to fill the RStudio viewer pane, but not require scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

The new version of [the swipeR package](https://github.com/stla/swipeR) provides a RStudio addin allowing to choose image files and to display them in the viewer pane. One can also visualize an animated GIF. Soon on CRAN.

[image]