# displaying ggplot .png in RStudio viewer pane with correct dimensions

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm writing a function to save a plot to the R temp directory, then display it in the viewer pane.  (Based in part on the last paragraph of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63625659/17303805).) If I save the plot as an .svg, it saves and shows up in the viewer pane at just the right size, based on the current pane dimensions:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grDevices)

plt <- ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))

dev.size()
# 5.250000 2.927083

plt_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".svg")
ggsave(plt_path, plt)
# Saving 5.25 x 2.93 in image

viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer(plt_path)
```

[image]

If I save it as a .png, however, the displayed image is way too big. (Note that `ggsave()` still reports saving it to the correct size.)

```
plt_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
ggsave(plt_path, plt)
# Saving 5.25 x 2.93 in image

viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer(plt_path)
```

[image]

The issue persists using `type = "cairo"`, and even if I manually set the `ggsave` dimensions:

```
dims <- dev.size(units = "in")
plt_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
ggsave(plt_path, plt, width = dims[[1]], height = dims[[2]], units = "in")
```

How can I save and display the .png image to match the viewer pane dimensions?

Comment: You need to save it at the correct `dpi` in ggsave. This will probably be 96 dpi

Comment: Just don't focus on the "viewer pane". That's no joke.

Comment: Here's a great blog post that walks through more of the issues and options around dpi in ggplot2: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/

Comment: @JonSpring thanks! I've definitely also struggled with some of the font sizing issues covered in the post - this is a great resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution needs to match that of your device. Default dpi is 300 in ggsave, but monitors are typically 96 dpi:

```r
dims <- dev.size(units = "in")
plt_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
ggsave(plt_path, plt, width = dims[[1]], height = dims[[2]], units = "in",
       dpi = 96)

viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer(plt_path)
```

[image]